# Laravel Can not submit forms

Tags: laravel, forms, redirect

I dont know why and when it happens. anything is ok in my site exept when Submit forms error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'` will be shown. see error in this link: [Click on submit](http://medabook.com/bdd/paytest). How can I fix it

```
            <form method="post"  action="{{ Route('pay')}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="offerid" value="1"/>
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="button">submit</button>
        </form>
```

this error is shown when submit all forms such laravel login form and ....

Comment: Show your code of the action which gets called when the user submits the form.

Comment: This problem is for all forms

Comment: Add the error and the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: you're missing a , or ) somewhere in your code at the line indicated in the error page that's displayed

Comment: error class is laravel class and I did not edit it. error is shown when submit all forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change any of files in your VENDOR folder.

rollback your changes .

Or copy past my default code:

```
$this->setContent(
            sprintf('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=%1$s" />

        <title>Redirecting to %1$s</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>.
    </body>
</html>', htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```